# Mousemove event firing even if mouse is still. Is there something wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when you move the mouse a stop/start button appears. Except the button fires several times after movement even if the mouse is still. Does anyone know if the error is in the code, if there is something lacking, or if it is something that has nothing to do with the code, but rather an external issue? What are my options?

I'm not experienced with coding so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

HTML

```
<div id="start-stop"></div>
```

CSS

```
#start-stop {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(pause.gif);
    cursor: pointer;

    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start-stop").fadeOut(3000);
    RndText();
    inter = setInterval(function() {

        RndText();
      }, 5000);
 });

$("body").mousemove(function() {
    $("#start-stop").finish().show().fadeOut(1500);
});

$(document).on('click', '#start-stop', function(){
  if (intervalRunning) {
    intervalRunning = false;
    clearInterval(inter);
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(play.gif)').fadeOut(1500);
  } else {
    intervalRunning = true;
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(pause.gif)').fadeOut(1500);
    inter = setInterval(function() {
      RndText();
    }, 3000);
  }
})
```

Comment: Please provide HTML & CSS as well

Comment: RndText() function is missing. Please add the code  in https://jsfiddle.net/ and provide the URL

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to get it to work but nothing seems to happen after I Run the codes in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o4g4agsw/

Comment: You probably need to debounce the `mousemove` handler. Otherwise, when you move the mouse, lots of events get queued, and it will process all of them sequentially.

Comment: Okay would you be able to suggest how I could go about doing so? I tried copying and pasting what was suggested in this link http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/ in the debounce section, but it didn't work

Comment: Where is RndText() ?

Comment: There is RndText(); in three areas in the script but I'm not sure what your advising. Like I said, I am inexperienced so I am a bit confused. Do you mean I have to insert something within the brackets of RndText();? Or are you suggesting something else?